# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse XML configuration from network_security_config

Tags: android, security, networking

```
// domain name
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain tools:ignore="NetworkSecurityConfig">org.dukehealth.colectiv</domain>

    <trust-anchors>
        <!--<certificates src="user" />-->
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
    <pin-set expiration=" Monday, 9 December, 2052"
        tools:ignore="NetworkSecurityConfig">

        <pin digest="SHA-256"
            tools:ignore="NetworkSecurityConfig">89:0B:5E:8E:D3:62:BC=</pin>

        <!-- Backup Pin for: currency-converter-demo.pdm.approov.io -->
        <pin digest="SHA-256"
            tools:ignore="NetworkSecurityConfig">89:0B:5E:8E:D3:62:BC:E0:F5:20:78:7E:CA:1</pin>
    </pin-set>

    <!-- TrustKit Android API -->
    <!-- enforce pinning validation -->

    <trustkit-config enforcePinning="true" disableDefaultReportUri="true">
        <!-- Add a reporting URL for pin validation reports -->
        
</domain-config>
```

**your text**

i got error not able to parse xml network security config i also add this to mainfest too please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the below namespace:
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
Also you need to have network-security-config tag and xml tag in your config xml
I am able to use your config in my project.